# how to call javascript function in layout content or view

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am calling the javascript function in the view of an layout. I have a common layout for different views but there are 2 views in specifically i want to check the `screen width`. In layout i can define the script but they will work on my whole application so just i want to mention them specifically in 2 views. I could have make 2 javascript files and include them in their respective views but i think this is not a good option.

How will i approach to this issue?

i have two views `mobile-view` and `desktop-view`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Put the JavaScript in a small `.js` file, and include that file in the specific views with `echo $this->Html->script('...');`

Option 2:

Create an element with the JavaScript in it (`echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('...');`), and reference that element from each of the views via `echo $this->element('...');`

Answer (score 0):

With the [HtmlHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-inline-javascript-blocks) you can buffer JavaScript script blocks and output them in the `<head>` or preferably at the end of the `<body>`, like so:

*Your View*

```
// Start a script block to be echoed at the end of the <body>
$this->Html->scriptStart(['block' => 'bottomScripts']);
echo "alert('Hi, it is JavaScript.');";
$this->Html->scriptEnd();
```

Nothing will happen unless you output the scripts and/or script blocks that are buffered inside the block called `bottomScripts` in a Layout or View:

*Your Layout*

```
    …
    <?= $this->fetch('bottomScripts'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```